# How to get a layout with height equal to 2/3 of free space

Tags: html, css, layout

How to achieve such a layout in CSS:

- First layer has a variable content.
- Under this layer must be a layer with ~66% of left free space(height).
- At the end is a layer which cover the rest of the free space.

The resolution should handle IE11.

- From the reason of IE grid module is not a solution.
- From the reason on variable content of first layer positioning with relative and absolute properties is also not a good idea.

The problem is the calculation of the height of a free space under a first layer.

It looks like the only solution is a quite new css module 'flex', but I didn't achieve a desirable effect. **Is it possible**?

[image: Expected result]

Comment: if 2 is 66.66% and 3 is 33.33%. The variable height of 1 wouldnt be 0%???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page contents are confined to 100% of the viewable area, the variable content is given as much as it likes, and the remaining space will just take up the rest of whatever's left. The remaining space is then split into one div of two thirds, and another div of one third (your 66.6% and 33.3% respectively) - I have colour coded them so that you can see them clearly.

I hope this helps, and I understand that you may have attempted to work this out yourself but just didn't include it in your question, just try to go more in depth into proving that you've went to good efforts to coming to your own answer, as that's the general etiquette of the site :)

```css
body { margin: 0; }

#page-contents { height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
#page-contents #variable-content { padding: 15px; background: red; color: white; flex: 0 1 auto; }

#page-contents #remaining-space { flex: 0 1 100%; background: blue; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

#page-contents #remaining-space #two-thirds { flex: 0 0 66.6666%; background: yellow; }
#page-contents #remaining-space #one-third { flex: 0 0 33.3333%; background: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="page-contents">
  <div id="variable-content">
    <p>Hi my name is Michael</p>
  </div>
  <div id="remaining-space">
    <div id="two-thirds">
    </div>
    <div id="one-third">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO He asked how to achieve it, not how the method of achieving it works - if he doesn't understand any parts of the answer he can Google for further clarification of flexbox

Comment: You know when i made my comment, and you know how your answer was at the time. Look at my edit and see what a good answer could look like\

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Apologies, I wasn't aware that code snippets are automatically pulled and runnable

Comment: @Keydose (Micheal). Thanks for your support. I spend a lot of time creating  a resolution using positioning and grid module techniques but I've lost with a flex. Maybe of beeing tired. Your solution works perfect. Words of appreciation for help. I've got a positive reputation also for beeing helpfull for the others. Can you vote and close this "ask"?

Comment: @JohnSmith Hi John, sorry for the late reply - I wasn't aware of this before but I did a bit of research... The changes required to make it work on IE11 are explicitly defining flex: 0 1 auto; for #variable-content and flex: 0 1 100%; for #remaining-space, this is because Internet Explorer flex properties default to flex: 0 0 instead of flex: 0 1... then also remove the calc() functions and replace them with 66.6666% and 33.3333% respectively as calc isn't supported by IE in a flex. I've updated the answer to reflect these changes